# Split a single-pair Hash into its key and value?

Tags: ruby

Does Ruby include a method that lets you take a single-pair Hash (example: `{:foo => 'bar'}`) and separate the key and value into two variables? I've written a small method to do this but I don't want to be redundant if Ruby can already do it. Back-of-napkin code provided below.

```
def split_hash hash
    key = hash.keys.first
    key, hash[key]
end
```

Usage:

```
hash = {:foo => 'bar'}
foo, bar = split_hash hash
# Expected: foo = :foo, bar = 'bar'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this

```
key, value = hash.first
```

Comment: That is damn clever. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Hash#flatten](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-flatten), which has been around since at least Ruby v1.9.3. Unlike [Array#flatten](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten), it does not flatten recursively.

```
hash = { foo: ['bar', 'boo'] }

foo, bar = hash.flatten
  #=> [:foo, ["bar", "boo"]]
```

I have encountered situations where it was helpful to know that (since Ruby v1.9) a hash's keys will retain their order of insertion. That's unusual, however, so the asker is advised to review their code to see if a design  that doesn't rely on key order might not be better.

Comment: Take that, @Sergio! When I first saw your answer I figured it was the only short answer, but it did offer a challenge. (I still prefer yours.)